# How can I list files with multiple criteria in bash and select a random one?

Tags: bash, shell, directory

I have a directory of files of this nature:

```
1985-08-28_state.txt  2001-04-29_state.txt  2016-12-29_state.txt
1985-08-29_state.txt  2001-04-30_state.txt  2016-12-30_state.txt
1985-08-30_state.txt  2001-05-01_state.txt  2016-12-31_state.txt
```

And I want to select all files for May-June and pick a random one from the list.

```
#!/bin/bash -u

states_path=./daily_states/
date="*-05-*_state.txt *-06-*_state.txt" #Patterns for May-June files
statefile=`ls ${states_path}/$date| shuf -n 1`

printf "$statefile \n"
```

but this is not able to access the second argument.

## Warning

```
ls: cannot access *-06-*_state.txt: No such file or directory
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

I am open to any other way of doing this.

## Alternate answer

I thought of another way of doing this. Not the most elegant solution. But I guess it works?

```
states_path=/daily_states/

statefile[0]=`ls ${states_path}/*-05-*_state.txt | shuf -n 1`
statefile[1]=`ls ${states_path}/*-06-*_state.txt | shuf -n 1`

randstate=$(($RANDOM % 2))

echo "${statefile[$randstate]}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your short solution has a few issues:

- Parses output of `ls`. Paths with spaces and so on might cause problems.
- The distribution of chosen files may not be uniform. If the first glob returns 100 files and the second glob returns one file, the chance of getting that one file from the second glob is way higher than getting a specific file from the first glob.

Here is an alternative that fixes these problems and is also way shorter:

```
 shuf -en1 daily_states/*-05-*_state.txt daily_states/*-06-*_state.txt
```

Both globs can also be combined as follows.

```
 shuf -en1 daily_states/*-0{5,6}-*_state.txt
```

As ghoti mentioned, consider using `shopt -s nullglob` -- better safe than sorry.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I like this solution. Mine was more stop-gap.

Comment: Nice. What provides shuf? Coreutils perhaps? It doesn't exist in FreeBSD or macOS by default. Note that with these, you'd still need to expand the multiple patterns, or come up with a method for aggregating them into a single pattern.

Comment: @ghoti I don't understand what you mean. Both patterns were expanded in this answer. All of the following commands are equal: `a=(x*); a+=(y*); printf %s\\n $"{a[@]}"`. `a=(x* y*); printf %s\\n $"{a[@]}"`. `printf %s\\n x* y*`. `printf %s\\n {x,y}*` . An array is not necessary.

Comment: Yes, `shuf` is provided by coreutils. The version is `shuf (GNU coreutils) 8.30`. An equivalent for `shuf -en1` is `shuffle -p1` on BSD.

Comment: There's a `shuffle` command in NetBSD, but it's not in FreeBSD or OpenBSD. My concern with your answer is that it recommends a solution that isn't necessarily related to the question or its tags. The Q doesn't mention an operating system, and you haven't provided a bash solution.

Comment: As for the other thing, sure, if all you want is to print a list of files, you don't need a data structure. But the OP didn't want a list, he wanted to "select a random one". You're doing that implicitly using functionality internal to `shuf`. My answer pulls a random element out of an array. Sorry, what are we arguing about again?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at how your variables expand. You set:

```
date="*-05-*_state.txt *-06-*_state.txt"
```

And then you set `$statefile` with the output of the command:

```
ls ${states_path}/*-05-*_state.txt *-06-*_state.txt| shuf -n 1
```

Now do you see the problem?

A better way to handle this might be using an array to store the patterns, and another array to collect filenames, since [parsing ls is problematic](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

states_path=./daily_states/
patterns=("*-05-*_state.txt" "*-06-*_state.txt")

a=()                    # initialize an empty array

shopt -s nullglob       # if no expansion occurs, expand to null

# Step through your patterns...
for monthpat in "${patterns[@]}"; do
  # And add files matching the pattern to the array.
  a+=( $states_path/$monthpat )
done

# Print the list
declare -p a
# or if you prefer,
printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"

# Or just print one random entry:
printf 'random: %s\n' "${a[ $(( $RANDOM % ${#a[@]} )) ]}"
```

Note that I'm not using `shuf`, because it's not part of bash, and not available on the operating systems I use bash (FreeBSD and macOS).

---

If you KNOW that you're only interested in these two months worth of files, you could express them as a single glob.  Thus:

```
a=( $states_path/*-0[56]-*_state.txt )
printf '%s\n' "${a[$(($RANDOM%${#a[@]}))]}"
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! This is getting quite a bit complicated as I was hoping to keep it a 1/2 liner using some kind of &, || etc.. Will try this.

Comment: I also thought of another (probably inelegant) way of doing this. Added to question. Thank you...Please let me know if you have a comment. I don't use bash much.

Comment: @ferengi, A for loop is the standard way to step through a list of things, like the patterns you provided in your question. And an array is the safest way to deal with the list of files. Your question didn't mention that you were looking for a half-liner, but I've added a very short alternative, without stuff like `nullglob` and comments, which may do.